# Get current session /process id from inside a mysql query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a table for pseudo array variable. That looks like

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MyArray`.`ArrayTable` (
  `ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Hash value of SessionID + ArrayName' ,
  `SessionID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `ArrayName` CHAR(26) NOT NULL 
          COMMENT '32 digit char - 6 digit longest process id (assumtion)' ,
  `Index` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `Value` TEXT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`, `SessionID`) )
ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

The table is not normalized yet, 'hope this will make it a little simpler to understand :)

To avoid collission between client, there should be a differentiator between client session. For that reason i think need to know current session/process id (just like "SHOW PROCESSLIST") but really need to know IN WHICH process the query are?

Comment: don't you have other identifying info you could use? the client's IP, the username etc, that actualy identify the client, not some pseudo randomness? Session/Process IDs could repeat over time

Comment: From one client ip and one user name could create many connection to server, so i don't thing it will work. But yes, you're pointing something i've missed, "Session/Process IDs could repeat over time". Now i'm thinking about adding creation time as variabel.

Comment: By the way, thread ids are reset after mysqld restart. As long as the server is running, the ids are not reused.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [connection_id()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_connection-id) function.